# How do I instruct Blend to generate working resource-loading code?

Tags: c#, wpf, blend

I'm designing a user interface in Blend, and need to open a new window on activating a button. The code that does this is very simple:

```
        var w = new Window1();
        w.Owner = this;
        _ = w.ShowDialog();
```

However, the new window fails to load its sample data. The failing code is auto-generated and can't really be influenced by me:

```
        Uri resourceUri = new Uri("ms-appx:/SampleData/Users/Users.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
        Application.LoadComponent(this, resourceUri);
```

The latter line fails with an ArgumentException: Cannot use absolute URI.

How do I open a new window in such a way that sample data may be loaded correctly?

Comment: Button click? Which means whilst running. How come you don't have a viewmodel consuming a real or mock model? Sample data is used just for designer prototyping purposes in my experience.

Comment: Yes, this is during prototyping.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `ms-appx:` and it works.
It should looks like: `Uri("/SampleData/Users/Users.xaml", UriKind ...`

Comment: This may be a compatiable issue when you use latest VS but work on a very old .net Framework version.